# Unable to run the sql statement with decrypt function and view on sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-10

I am getting an error when I run the query on sql server 2008 on my laptop.
I am using Windows 2010 and sql version 2008 which was installed by default on windows 10.

When I run  the view and some procedure I am getting an error-

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'MASTER.DBO.PASSCODE'.

The same queries and procedures I have been using on another server on desktop,that runs fine over there.I have restored the database on my laptop.
Some of the procedues are executing and some of select statements.

I am getting error when I execute the Views and some procedures with return value and Select statement with encrypt and decrypt function.

I googled the same error ,what I read was to run the script 'u_tables.sql'on sql server....But that did not helped for me.I am still geting the error when I exec the procedures and select statements( using decrypt function)

Please help me to resolve the same.

Comment: only you are in position to know more about that error,since we don't have access to shcema of your database

Comment: Did you try changing the DB before running the code? Seems like you are running from master DB which is not where you normally put your user data tables